# Make bibliography "invisible" (with bibtex)

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

While working on a long LateX document I would like the citations to be displayed correctly, but the bibliography itself not being added to the document.

Is it possible to make the bibliography being compiled, but not producing output? (Maybe it's not even difficult, and I am just being stupid...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `\include` and `\includeonly`:

```
\documentclass{book}
...
% \includeonly{}
\begin{document}
...<the document>...

\include{biblio}
\end{document}
```

The file `biblio.tex` will contain the commands to produce the bibliography: the `thebibliography` environment or the `\bibliography` command if you use the traditional method with BibTeX.

When you are sure about the correctness of the references, uncomment the `\includeonly` line.

As lockstep says, with **biblatex** it's sufficient not to use `\printbibliography`.

Comment: So what I have to do is to list all included `tex` files in the includeonly command (which is not commented out...). Then the references are displayed correctly, but the bibliography is not appended to the document.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use the `comment` package and to enclose the `\bibliography` command (in the body of your document) inside a `comment` environment initially deactivated; i.e., schematically to write something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\includecomment{comment}
%\excludecomment{comment}

\begin{document}

\cite{key1},\cite{key2},...,\cite{keyn}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\begin{comment}
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{comment}

\end{document}
```

then, process your document in the usual way: `pdflatex+bibtex+pdflatex+pdflatex` to get the citations and the bibliography, and then to activate the `comment` environment (by uncommenting the     `\excludecomment{comment}` line and commenting out `\includecomment{comment}`
) and then run `pdflatex` one more time.

Comment: That's certainly a possibility, but I recompile after every other sentence and wouldn't want to change this every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
\printbibliography[keyword=xxx]
```

were "xxx" is a keyword you don't use. This way the correct files are compiled but no bibliography is added to the document.

Comment: This command must be from a particular package? LaTeX does not recognize it.

Comment: @Rainer: but your solution applies to `biblatex` bibliographies, and fuenfundachtzig needs a `bibtex` approach.

Comment: Assuming the use of `biblatex` is permitted, there's a much more simple solution: Don't include `\printbibliography` in your document.